# Two Subquery-Select Tables Resulting In Same Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

Using SQL Server Managment Studio 2016.

When I execute the following query, SUM(COLUMN_D) and SUM(COLUMN_E) show the same results.  However, the subquery table for column D (TBL_1) is using different information than the subquery table for column E (TBL_2).

```
   SELECT EMPLOYEE, TBL_1.STATE, EMP.NAME, SUM(COLUMN_D) 'Column D', SUM(COLUMN_E) 'Column E'
   FROM
   (
       SELECT T1.*, T2.STATE
       FROM
           (
            SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEE, ACCOUNT, MAX(DATE) 'Date', 1 'COLUMN_D'
            FROM TRANSACTION
            GROUP BY EMPLOYEE, ACCOUNT
           ) T1
           LEFT JOIN LOCATION T2 ON T2.ACCOUNT=T1.ACCOUNT
           )TBL_1 

           JOIN
    (
        SELECT TT1.*,TT2.STATE
        FROM
            (
             SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT, PROVIDER, MAX(JOB_TITLE) 'Job', 1 'COLUMN_E'
             FROM EMPLOYEE_LIST
             GROUP BY ACCOUNT, PROVIDER
             )TT1
             LEFT JOIN LOCATION TT2 ON TT2.ACCOUNT=TT1.ACCOUNT
             )TBL_2 on TBL_2.ACCOUNT=TBL_1.ACCOUNT
    join EMPLOYER EMP on EMP.EMPID=TBL_1.EMPLOYEE and EMP.EMPID=TBL_2.PROVIDER
    WHERE TBL1.STATE IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY EMPLOYEE, TBL_1.STATE, EMP.NAME
    ORDER BY EMPLOYEE, EMP.NAME
```

When executed, the results look like the following:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clzzN.jpg)

The TRANSACTION table for TBL_1 shows the number of transactions; The LOCATION table for both TBL_1 and TBL_2 show the different locations; The EMPLOYEE_LIST table for TBL_2 shows the list of employees and the work load (For instance, employee A can have a work load of 40 but only had 10 transactions); The EMPLOYER table shows more detail information like the full name of the EMPLOYEE.

So, the results should look like the following:
[Should Look Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbM2A.jpg)

Is their a problem with how I join TBL_2 to TBL_1 that is causing the same number for both COLUMN_D and COLUMN_E?

Sample Data: TRANSACTION

```
    EMPLOYEE   ACCOUNT   DATE                       BILLED   CHGAMOUNT
    XAC425     100001    2017-03-14 00:00:00.000    B        200.05
    XAC468     100001    2017-03-10 00:00:00.000    B        158.69
    XAC468     100002    2017-03-07 00:00:00.000    B        10.23
    XAC499     100003    2017-03-07 00:00:00.000    B        30.99
    XAC499     100004    2017-03-25 00:00:00.000    B        25.99
    XAC499     100005    2017-03-10 00:00:00.000    B        101.22
    XAC499     100002    2017-03-07 00:00:00.000    B        105.89
```

Sample Data: LOCATION

```
    EMPLOYEE   ACCOUNT   STATE        ACTIVE 
    XAC425     100001    CALIFORNIA   Y    
    XAC468     100001    UTAH         Y   
    XAC468     100002    UTAH         Y   
    XAC499     100003    ARIZONA      Y      
    XAC499     100004    ARIZONA      Y      
    XAC499     100005    ARIZONA      Y    
    XAC499     100002    ARIZONA      Y
```

Sample Data: EMPLOYEE_LIST

```
    PROVIDER   ACCOUNT   JOB TITLE LEVEL   
    XAC425     100001    WORKER    1       
    XAC468     100001    WORKER    1       
    XAC468     100002    WORKER    1       
    XAC499     100003    MANAGER   2            
    XAC499     100004    MANAGER   2
    XAC499     100005    MANAGER   2
    XAC499     100002    MANAGER   2
```

Sample Data: EMPLOYER

```
    EMPID     NAME           Address            City     State  Zip
    XAC425    John Smith     123 Walnut Street  Irving   CA     90265
    XAC468    Kerry Wong     456 North Road     Chicago  IL     60658  
    XAC499    Tim Jones      12 Post Road       New York NY     00014      
    XAC500    Todd Bullock   1234 18th Street   Tucson   AZ     56586
```

Comment: Just to clarify more on this request, I am basically trying to display data from COLUMN D based on TBL_1 and a different set of data from COLUMN E base don TBL_2 based on common fields: EMPLOYEE, ACCOUNT, and STATE.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the aliases on the middle layer (the first layer of the subquery). Try the following:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE, TBL_1.STATE, EMP.NAME, SUM(COLUMN_D) 'Column D', SUM(COLUMN_E) 'Column E'
   FROM
   (
       SELECT EMPLOYEE, ACCOUNT, [Date], COLUMN_D, T2.STATE
       FROM
           (
            SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEE, ACCOUNT, MAX(DATE) 'Date', 1 'COLUMN_D'
            FROM TRANSACTION
            GROUP BY EMPLOYEE, ACCOUNT
           ) T1
           LEFT JOIN LOCATION T2 ON T2.ACCOUNT=T1.ACCOUNT
           )TBL_1 

           JOIN
    (
        SELECT ACCOUNT, PROVIDER,  Job, COLUMN_E,TT2.STATE
        FROM
            (
             SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT, PROVIDER, MAX(JOB_TITLE) 'Job', 1 'COLUMN_E'
             FROM EMPLOYEE_LIST
             GROUP BY ACCOUNT, PROVIDER
             )TT1
             LEFT JOIN LOCATION TT2 ON TT2.ACCOUNT=TT1.ACCOUNT
             )TBL_2 on TBL_2.ACCOUNT=TBL_1.ACCOUNT
    join EMPLOYER EMP on EMP.EMPID=TBL_1.EMPLOYEE and EMP.EMPID=TBL_2.PROVIDER
    WHERE TBL1.STATE IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY EMPLOYEE, TBL_1.STATE, EMP.NAME
    ORDER BY EMPLOYEE, EMP.NAME
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I get the same result as I did before.

Comment: @Bryant can you please post some sample data?

Comment: thank you for your help.  I added some sample tables and I hope they are sufficient.  I may be making this question more difficult than it should when it comes to explaining.  Since the query is setup with two different subquery tables (TBL_1) and (TBL_2), the count for both COLUMN D and COLUMN E should not be equal.  They should produce different counts.  That is the part of the query where I can't get to work properly.  And it may be because of my joins.  Both TBL_1 and TBL_2 are looking at different subqueries.  But, the result shows the same number for both, which is not right.

Comment: I looked at this, and now I am even more confused. Let's give this one more try. Can you please provide the following: A sentence in English (no tech talk) describing what you want each row in the result to contain.